# mysql query command

Tags: mysql, sql

```
1:SELECT * FROM TABLE; // its working... :)      

2:SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE; // its not working... :(  

3:SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id; // its working... :(   

4:SELECT * FROM TABLE WHEREad8a9sdfasdfasdf; // its working... ??
```

what is the explanation?  and how can mysql prevent to not return query result when I run the forth query or the second one.

thanks alot.

Comment: Why have you changed your question ?? Also, you want to say forth or third one because second is not working ?

Comment: sorry about changing, i need a solution to handle the issue in the mysql level not in my code.is there a solution to change mysql stuff to check the value after where-clause ? something like validation in code stuff.

Comment: 1. Mark the correct answer for your old question. 2. Open a new question and explain the problem as best as you can(read your question two-three times before posting to check errors...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` requires a condition.  MySQL will convert a value to a boolean, if necessary, which is why (1) and (3) work and why (2) does not work.

The last one works because it is interpreted as:

```
SELECT *  
FROM TABLE as WHEREad8a9sdfasdfasdf;
```

That is, `WHEREad8a9sdfasdfasdf` is a table alias.  (Note:  I don't use `as` for table aliases; I am only using it here to emphasize what is happening.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Gordon already wroted I will add this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id; -- its working... :(
```

This will return the rows from that table where id is not null

Here is a demonstration:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31d60a4bdbf74f7cb16d5ce4918db751)

Also, I had to add `` around table name TABLE to make this query's work...